# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER

Tags: php

i have this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in line 14 " i would like to calculate difference between two dates

```
function datedifference()
{
   $res=dbconnect()->exec("SELECT DATEDIFF("2017-06-25", "2017-06-15");");

   echo $res;
}
```

Comment: use single quotes for dates

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your string syntax is wrong, you have not escaped the `"` quotes inside the string, you can either use `'` single-quote or escape the double quote:

Single-quote:

```
$res = dbconnect()->exec("SELECT DATEDIFF('2017-06-25', '2017-06-15');");
```

Escaped double quote:

```
$res = dbconnect()->exec("SELECT DATEDIFF(\"2017-06-25\", \"2017-06-15\");");
```

Comment: Please, be sure to accept the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting buttons.